# Однородность определений после определяемого слова

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-неоднородные-определения

"Определения (согласованные), стоящие после определяемого слова, как правило, являются однородными и поэтому разделяются запятыми.", - Лопатин (У Розенталя отсутствует "как правило").

Мы беседовали о вашем старом красном автомобиле. 
Автомобиль какой? красный, красный а. какой? старый, старый красный а. чей? ваш. Неоднородные определения, выраженные местоимением и прилагательными.

Мы беседовали об автомобиле вашем старом, красном.
Слово ваше высокопарное, фальшивое, книжное действовало на нас резко.
Пошел снег первый ? зимний … 
В лагере новом, летнем, оздоровительном … 
Друг мой сердечный …

Чувствуется, что здесь как раз не действует "как правило". Понятно, что они не могут быть однородными (местоимение и однородная связка остальных) и в постпозиции.

Получается, что правило неполное? Или какие могут быть другие оправдания этому? Или на самом деле нужно следовать правилу даже в этом случае? Или это опять влияние быстроты произношения … ?!
И совершенно понятно, что лучше писать "ваше слово высокопарное …" , но иногда ситуация требует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я коротко еще раз отвечу на вопрос, так как мне кажется, что **тема  не раскрыта.**

Вопрос был задан об **однородности** ряда согласованных определений, стоящих после  после определяемого слова.

Как известно, такой ряд обычно **обособляется**, но может не обособляться, если на него падает **логическое ударение,** например:

(1) **По дороге** **зИмней, скУчной** тройка борзая бежит.

Но это **авторский выбор,** характерный прием для поэтической речи. Эта же строка может  включать обособленное определение:

(2) **По дорОге,** **зИмней, скУчной,** тройка борзая бежит.

Обратим внимание, что в обоих случаях определения выражают разные признаки и **являются неоднородными** (это относительное и качественное прилагательное).

Но если такой ряд стоит после определяемого слова, то **определения приравниваются к однородным**, запятая ставится.

Здесь действует **формальный признак:** неоднородные определения не могут находиться в постпозиции, так как в этом случае на каждое определение падает ударение, они произносятся с перечислительной интонацией.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Согласованные определения являются **однородными**:

8) если **стоят после определяемого существительного** (в этом положении каждое из определений непосредственно связано с существительным и имеет одинаковую смысловую самостоятельность): Я видел женщину молодую, прекрасную, добрую, интеллигентную, обаятельную (Ч.); Я буду тогда обладать истиной вечной, несомненной (Т.).

**Возможны отступления от правила:** а) в стихотворной речи, что связано с ритмомелодикой стиха: Здравствуйте, дни голубые осенние (Бр.); б) в сочетаниях терминологического характера: груша зимняя позднеспелая; трубы тонкостенные электросварные нержавеющие; кран мостовой электрический грейферный; брюки серые суконные; астра ранняя махровая;

Отметим, что в приведенных примерах Розенталя с неоднородными определениями нет **перечислительной интонации.**

Устойчивые выражения вида **"дочурка ваша любимая, друг мой единственный"** также можно отнести к исключениям: неоднородные определения после определяемого слова не разделяются запятой.

Comment: "Где же она? Кто? Да дочурка ваша любимая." Почему между ваша и любимая нет запятой, если они являются однородными? (Чувственно понятно, но нужно конкретное правило, где был бы разъяснен этот момент). Ведь в правиле сказано:  "если стоят после определяемого существительного, то ставится между ними запятая". Обращаясь к другому правилу, относящемуся к теме не однородных, а обособленных определений, мы видим, что там написано: "опр. оборот, стоящий после ... притяж. мест. не отделяется из-за тесного примыкания".

Comment: Но ведь это не оборот, а одиночное определение. Конечно, нет перечислительной интонации, возможно, образуют какое-то единое словосочетание, тесно связаны и т.д.

Comment: Ответ дополнен, посмотрите.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ, это именно тот момент, который изначально подразумевался в вопросе (наверное, не очень хорошо сформулирован).  Как мне кажется, в справочной литературе недостаточно подробно говорится о подобных явлениях, а литературу с разбором подобных моментов сложно найти. Да, я, конечно, видел эти пункты у Розенталя, но, наверное, я слишком придираюсь к формулировкам, ведь это разговорный пример, а не стихотворный.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь все определения согласованные, одиночные, все стоят после определяемого слова.

[Знаки препинания при обособленных согласованных определениях](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/znaki-prepinaniya-pri-obosoblennyih-67293.html): Нераспространенные определения, относящиеся к существительным, не имеющим впереди определений, обособляются, только если они имеют пояснительно-конкретизирующее значение: ***Я часто находил у себя записки, короткие и тревожные (Ч.); Утром он разворачивает газету, местную (Сол.); Распахиваю в ночь, черную, звездную, соррентийскую, створку окна (Цвет.).***

***Мы беседовали об автомобиле вашем, старом, красном.*** -"Старом, красном" - конкретизирующее значение, обособляем.

Определение ВАШЕМ не обособляем. [Там же](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/znaki-prepinaniya-pri-obosoblennyih-67293.html): Нераспространенные определения, стоящие после определяемого имени существительного, не имеющего впереди определения, не обособляются, **если это существительное нуждается в определении,** так как само по себе не способно выразить полноценный смысл в данном контексте. *Неужели это и есть прогресс человеческий (Зал.)*

Здесь не обособляем ВАШЕ по тому же принципу: ***Слово ваше - высокопарное, фальшивое, книжное - действовало на нас резко.*** 
Остальные определения уже вторичны, имеют уточняющее значение - обособляем. (Я предпочла тире.)

Ср.:***Слово высокопарное, фальшивое, книжное действовало на него резко. (И.Бунин)*** - Каждое из ... определений непосредственно связано с определяемым словом и имеет самостоятельное логическое ударение (там же). Не обособляем, а только разделяем однородные определения запятой.

***Пошел снег, первый,  зимний*** … Одиночные определения стоят после определяемого слова и имеют уточняющее значение. (Снег, как ни странно, бывает не только зимний).

***В лагере, новом, летнем оздоровительном,*** … - Здесь определения имеют уточняющий характер. Сочетание "летнем оздоровительном" обособляем, но запятую между ними не ставим, так как это термин, обозначающий статус лагеря.

***Друг мой сердечный*** … - устойчивое выражение, фразеологизм.

Comment: Мне по душе такой подход, неформальный, в основу которого положено понимание обособления как пояснения и конкретизации.

Answer (score 0):

1) Эта тема разбирается у Розенталя и Лопатина **в двух местах:** обособленные и необособленные  определения; однородные и неоднородные определения. Поэтому внимательно прочитайте всю информацию.

2) **Никогда не работайте с искусственно придуманными вами предложениями**, так как это напрасная трата времени, в том числе Вашего. Зайдите в Нацкорпус, выберите примеры из классической и современной литературы. Если все таки хотите придумать свои примеры, они должны быть взяты из жизни и связаны с конкретной ситуацией. **Пишите так, как будто ВЫ разговариваете с кем-то о погоде и машинах.**

2) Ряд определений, стоящий **после определяемого слова**, может быть **обособленным или необособленным**. Но вот **неоднородным он быть не может,** так как на каждый однородный член должно падать ударение, мы не можем в одну фразу произнести несколько неоднородных прилагательных.

К определяемому слову может тесно примыкать только местоимение (слОво ваше, дрУг мой),ударение на него не падает.

**Это основная информация,** а дальше действуйте по ситуации и согласно правилам.

4) **Попробуем разобрать Ваши примеры.**

(1)  О вашем автомобиле, **старом, красном**, мы уже раньше говорили. Или:  Об автомобиле, **вашем, старом, красном**, мы уже раньше говорили.

(2) Пошел  снег, первый, белый, пушистый. (Снег бывает только зимним).

(3) В области работает много лагерей, **новых, летних, оздоровительных.**

В этих примерах ряд определений обособлен, причем он приравнен к однородному (запятые ставятся), хотя по смыслу включает как однородные, так и неоднородные определения.

Comment: "Мы уже говорили об автомобиле, вашем(,) старом, красном" — здесь запятая в скобках не нужна .

Comment: почему не нужна?

Comment: "При отсутствии предшествующего определения два последующих одиночных определения обособляются или не обособляются в зависимости от авторской интонационно-смысловой нагрузки, а также их местоположения" (Розенталь);

Comment: Ряд "ваш, старый, красный" мне кажется бессмысленным, в отличие от "ваш старый, красный" или даже так: "автомобиль ваш, старый, красный"

Comment: Здесь такая авторская интонационно-смысловая нагрузка: собеседник подчеркивает, о какой машине идет речь: именно о вАшем (а не о каком-то другом), старом, красном автомобиле.  А если понятна принадлежность автомобиля, то местоимение можно поставить перед существительным.

Comment: Немного изменила порядок слов, чтобы ситуация была более понятной.